# Mongo DB Backup & restore

Tags: mongodb

I have a DB with 150GB of data's . Am using MongoDump and Mongorestore method to back and restore.

My Production server is running with Mongo 2.2 and Test server is with 2.6.1

When i take a back up from production server Mongo2.2 its taking long time to complete the back up for 150GB of data. And restoration take 6-8 Hours. its not completed without error, some times restore is dropped automatically and we need to run the restore again or restore the missed collection.

is there a best way to to take a backup and restore method, where we can save time and run it without Errors?

Regards,
Rishi

Comment: You should ask on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can couple of options for native backup and restore functionality and these are listed very well in the documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backup/.

Just to summarize, as your data grows, mongodump / mongorestore becomes less ideal for backup / restore purpose and you should start looking at other options like:

- File system based snapshots or LVM snapshots (Since you are in EC2, this should be fairly straight forwards)
- MMS Backup

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to **Backup and Restore Using LVM** on a Linux System.

**Creating a Snapshot:**

```
lvcreate --size 100M --snapshot --name mdb-snap01 /dev/vg0/mongodb
```

**Archive a Snapshot**:

```
umount /dev/vg0/mdb-snap01
dd if=/dev/vg0/mdb-snap01 | gzip > mdb-snap01.gz
```

**Restore a Snapshot**:

```
lvcreate --size 1G --name mdb-new vg0
gzip -d -c mdb-snap01.gz | dd of=/dev/vg0/mdb-new
mount /dev/vg0/mdb-new /srv/mongodb
```

**Restore Directly from a Snapshot**:

```
umount /dev/vg0/mdb-snap01
lvcreate --size 1G --name mdb-new vg0
dd if=/dev/vg0/mdb-snap01 of=/dev/vg0/mdb-new
mount /dev/vg0/mdb-new /srv/mongodb
```

**Remote Backup Storage:**

```
umount /dev/vg0/mdb-snap01
dd if=/dev/vg0/mdb-snap01 | ssh username@example.com gzip > /opt/backup/mdb-snap01.gz
lvcreate --size 1G --name mdb-new vg0
ssh username@example.com gzip -d -c /opt/backup/mdb-snap01.gz | dd of=/dev/vg0/mdb-new
mount /dev/vg0/mdb-new /srv/mongodb
```